# The stats field in statsComponent

Tags: java, solr

In my project, I need statistics two fields by solr stats facet. Can I add two parameters in stats field and statistics them at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [StatsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent) you can pass stats.field multiple times to receive them all at a single request e.g. `stats.field=price&stats.field=popularity`

```
e.g. http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&stats=true&stats.field=price&stats.field=popularity&rows=0&indent=true
```

You can also pass multiple facet fields e.g. `stats.facet=inStock&stats.facet=popularity`